# Matching content in two different columns-MySQL

Tags: mysql, matching

Let's say I have a list of person names and a list of social media URL's (that might or might not contain a portion of the person names).

I'm trying to see if the full name is *not* contained in the list of URL's I have. I don't think a "not like" would work here (because the URL has plenty of other characters to throw back a result), but I can't think of any other way to address this. Any tips? The closest I could find was from this:

[Matching partial words in two different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511914/matching-partial-words-in-two-different-columns)

But I'm unsure if that applies here.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE url LIKE '%name%'` % means any characters even whitespace. Then just check if it returned any rows.

From mysql doc:

> % matches any number of characters, even zero characters.

```
mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE 'David_';
-> 1
mysql> SELECT 'David!' LIKE '%D%v%';
-> 1
```

So let's say these are your url's in your list:
website.com/peterjohnson
website.com/jackmiller
website.com/robertjenkins

Then if you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%peter%'
```

It would return 1 row.

You can also use NOT LIKE so you will get all the rows not containing the name.