# String comparison using BigQuery

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, string-comparison

I have a table with people and their hometown names, but there are same cities with different written, see:

| Name | Hometown |
| --- | --- |
| João | São Paulo |
| Maria | Sao Paul |
| Pedro | São Paulo. |
| Maria | S. Paulo |

And I need to process this in order to formalize that data to be like this:

| Name | Hometown |
| --- | --- |
| João | São Paulo |
| Maria | São Paulo |
| Pedro | São Paulo |
| Maria | São Paulo |

- The dataset has more than 2400 distinct values so I can't hard code.
- I have a Country table dimension with all cities and their correct names.

I tried [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33433925/is-there-a-way-to-measure-string-similarity-in-google-bigquery#comment126356697_57499387) and would it be exactly what I need but does not work with my entire dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach (considering you have lookup table with all proper cities names) for purpose of example  - I have it as CTE with just few ones

```
with cities as (
  select 'São Paulo' as city union all 
  select 'Los Angeles' union all 
  select 'Dnipro' union all 
  select 'Kyiv'
)
select Name, City as Hometown
from your_table 
left join cities 
on soundex(Hometown) = soundex(city)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: you obviously need to take care of potential duplication in case if some cities sounds similar, in this case adding country constraints might help ...

Comment: `soundex` is not an appropriate "sounds like" algorithm, especially for non-English words. It only takes into account the first four consonants. There will be many, many false positives.

Comment: this is just an option to try. meantime, as OP mentioned , he has table with all correct city names so there should be a match. as of false-positives - I mentioned in the note (at the bottom of my answer) that there will be dups that still needs to be addressed. :o) if country field exists - it can help. also dups can be further eliminated using different (for example distance) algo, etc.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I appreciate your thought and tried it! unfortunately I had a lot of duplications for apparently two main reasons: a lot of cities sounds very similar and also as Schwern said, seems like it does not works well with non-English words and even the ones which does not sound similar returns the same result with `soundex`, see `select city, soundex(city) from unnest(['Barcelos','Brasileira','Brasília','Brejolândia','Barros Cassal','Berizal','Brejo Alegre']) as city`

Comment: See notes in my answer - at the very bottom, as well as comments above on use additional algos like distance for example to resolve dups. You can find plenty examples here on SO including answered by me

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I will enrich my data to use state constraints and see the improvements, it would be great if i could solve this entirely by using only BigQuery

Answer (score 2):

First, the basics.

1. Strip non-letters.
2. Case fold.
3. Convert to ASCII equivalents.

The first one is straight-forward, strip out everything which isn't a letter so `São Paulo` and `São Paulo.` are both `SãoPaulo`.

Case folding is also straight-forward, change everything to lower or upper case. `são paulo` and `São Paulo` compare the same.

Finally, convert them to the normal ASCII equivalents. For example, `são` becomes `sao`.

With this normalization done, the issues of spaces, extra characters, accents, and cases are taken are of. I would recommend doing this outside of BigQuery and in a language like Python. Do a `select distinct` and transform and compare each value using libraries such as [unidecode](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/).

---

You can then employ some heuristics to try and find "close enough" matches. One example is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is the number of substitutions, insertions, and deletions one needs to do to turn one string into another. [Python has a Levenshtein library](https://pypi.org/project/Levenshtein/).

For example, `Sao Paul` and `Sao Paulo` have a Levenshtein distance of one; add one letter. `S Paulo` and `Sao Paulo` have a Levenshtein distance of two, add two letters. `Sao Paulo` and `Saint Paul` have a Levenshtein distance of four; change o to i, add n and t, remove o.

Again, I'd recommend doing this with a regular programming language and then writing the normalized results back to BigQuery.

Comment: You supplied great content and explanation and for its reason I upvoted your answer but ended up accepting Mikhael one because it had satisfactory results when added constraints and I could solve all by using BigQuery. I just want to register my gratefulness.